# CocosBuilder2.1 ,How to fix my program for iPhone 5 screen

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5, cocosbuilder

Image of my program:

[image]

I tried to add iPhone 5 resolution support to my CocosBuilder:

View->Edit Resolutions... ->Add Predenfined Resolution->iPhone 5 Landscape->OK

I also used percentages to setup my content position and sizes

I also added a Default-568@2x.png image into xcode, but the size of my CCSprites and all images still look like 480x320 on the simulator as depicted in the link above.

is there any solution?

Comment: when i look at the logging on the image, cocos2d is displaying the proper surface size. does not seem to either a cocos nor a an xcode issue.

Comment: but the white picture is suppose to be 1136x640

like http://imgur.com/ZfwDjOM the image in this link.

I tried the method on this website
http://tomatofactory.com/cocosbuilder-iphone-5-resolution/

but it doesn't show entirely correct